# Drawing a line after an arbitrary number of SVG tspan elements

Tags: svg, position

I'd like to use SVG to create an XSLT template to generate PDFs of orders placed in a system. The idea is that I have N order positions (say between 3 and 10) which I want displayed row by row and with a horizontal line after the bottom-most row and the usual total row.

Here's is an illustration:
[image: How to position the line (and last order row) relative to the last position row?]

My problem is that I cannot find out how to position the horizontal line and the final total row relative the last order position row. Here's what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/hg3hzd4j/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="300" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g transform="translate(10, 15)">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="stroke:#000; fill: #FFFF00" fill-opacity="0.2" stroke-opacity="0.2"></rect>
  <g transform="translate(10, 0)">
  <line id="guide1" x1="160" y1="0" x2="160" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
  <line id="guide2" x1="220" y1="0" x2="220" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
    <g>
      <text x="0" y="20">
        <tspan>Mono layer</tspan>
        <tspan x="100">$50</tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">4</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$200</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="20">Single layer</tspan>
        <tspan x="100">$25</tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">3</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$75</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="20">Double layer</tspan>
        <tspan x="100">$45</tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">3</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$135</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="20">Triple layer</tspan>
        <tspan x="100">$65</tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">1</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$65</tspan>
        <!-- I'd like a line here -->
        <!-- And the grand total row -->
        <tspan x="0" dy="30">Total</tspan>
        <tspan x="100"></tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">11</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$475</tspan>
      </text>
      <line x1="0" y1="150" x2="100%" y2="150" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm by no means an expert so any suggestion is greatly appreciated. I thought I could define each position row with something similar to a DIV and that everything would shift down automatically. But obviously not.

Comment: Does it need to be SVG? This would be quite easy to do with a HTML table

Comment: Technically, it could be done with HTML. I just have one part that's SVG but that shouldn't be much trouble to embed. The whole A4 layout has already been made in SVG however so that would save me the trouble of rewriting it in HTML. Moreover, the whole thing will ultimately be transformed to PDF so I'd rather do it from SVG. Or do you know any HTML to PDF converter that works well and preserves SVG objects?

Comment: How are you currently converting the SVG to PDF? I think there is two options: either use a table and convert the html/svg into PDF or you can calculate the coordinates for the line using the number of rows. Guess we just have to figure out which one would be easiest/ more maintainable :-)

Comment: Using inkscape. The whole process is scripted and quite streamlined For HTML to PDF, I tried wkhtmltopdf but I find the processing of font weights rather inconsistent. SVG embedded into HTML is rendered correctly by wkhtmltopdf however. Blending HTML for the table and SVG for the payment slip at the bottom would be a workable option.

Comment: This is how you could do it by adding a foreign object table into your svg: http://jsfiddle.net/10f6rcgq/  You could give it a try in your exporter and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks @StaceyBurns. Alas, Inkscape won't render foreign objects, therefore the table won't appear in the PDF produced. What do you use to convert SVG to PDF?

Comment: If we are talking about web design I would normally send it back to the server to generate. Are you manually creating the html/svg code and converting it to pdf using inkscape or something?

Comment: Eventually I concluded that the right approach was to use an html template with embedded svg elements. There's too much overhead involved when writing a table in svg.

Answer (score 0):

Add the value the `dy` attribute of each order line to the `y` coordinate of the `<text>` element.  That will get you the absolute Y position of the baseline of the last order line.

```
20 + (20 + 20 + 20) = 80.
```

Add an appropriate amount of extra padding to get you below the descenders of characters in the last row (eg. 10).

Then set the `y1` and `y2` coords of your line to the final value (90 in this example).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="300" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g transform="translate(10, 15)">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="stroke:#000; fill: #FFFF00" fill-opacity="0.2" stroke-opacity="0.2"></rect>
  <g transform="translate(10, 0)">
  <line id="guide1" x1="160" y1="0" x2="160" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
  <line id="guide2" x1="220" y1="0" x2="220" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
    <g>
      <text x="0" y="20">
        <tspan>Mono layer</tspan>
        <tspan x="100">$50</tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">4</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$200</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="20">Single layer</tspan>
        <tspan x="100">$25</tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">3</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$75</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="20">Double layer</tspan>
        <tspan x="100">$45</tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">3</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$135</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="20">Triple layer</tspan>
        <tspan x="100">$65</tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">1</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$65</tspan>
        <!-- I'd like a line here -->
        <!-- And the grand total row -->
        <tspan x="0" dy="30">Total</tspan>
        <tspan x="100"></tspan>
        <tspan x="160" style="text-anchor:end">11</tspan>
        <tspan x="220" style="text-anchor:end">$475</tspan>
      </text>
      <line x1="0" y1="90" x2="100%" y2="90" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks that's indeed a no brainer if you have a given and constant number of rows. As soon as I have 5 or 6 I'd have to recompute the `y` coordinate manually.

Comment: It's a long time since I did any XSLT, but you should be able to count the lines and caculate the correct Y coordinate.